# Reformatting a list of timestamps to account for overlapping times with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of timestamps associated with account ids from different vendors and I am trying to reformat the list to account for overlap for users that show up in both vendor's timestamps.

Here is an image of an example table I am working with:
[image: Example Timestamps Table]

Here is an image of an example output table I desire to create:
[image: Desired Output]

In the example above, vendor ID 3 is a newly created vendor to indicate an overlap for when the user AXY_2 showed up in vendor ID 1 and 2. There are two cases where overlap can occur:

- **Case 1)** One vendor's ID timestamp completely overlaps with another vendor's ID timestamp (shown in the example image above).
- **Case 2)** There is only a partial overlap between the two vendors.

I have currently written a python script that works; I am still verifying that the script correctly accounts for overlap. However, since I am working on a huge list of data (over 10 million rows), the script takes over an hour to run.

I was wondering if anybody has a better way to solve this problem (ideally using Python).

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you are able to use other packages and what adding the code snippet of your method.

Comment: @GodWin, I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask. I am currently using Python and pandas to solve this problem. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Scans complicate the provision of assistance, as does the lack of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.